# Controller returning microsoft chart as an image to AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an action to set up MS chart and returns the image file to AJAX call.

This is my action

```
 public FileResult MyAction(ICollection<MyModel> lstModel)
    {
         using (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart())
        {
            // Here is my code to set up points to the chart...

            MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
            chart.SaveImage(imageStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            chart.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.SystemDefault;
            return File(imageStream.GetBuffer(), @"image/png");               
        }
    }
```

This is my jquery AJAX call

```
function ShowChart() {        
    var url = "/MyController/MyAction";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,            
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',            
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),            
        success: function (data) {                          
            $("#imgChart").attr("src", data);               

        }
    });
}
```

But the chart is not getting displayed. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You can't return binary data from an AJAX request. One way to do this would be to convert the `imageStream` to a base64 encoded string and return that instead, as that format can easily be displayed on the client.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you very much for your swift response. I converted imagestream to a base64. It is working now. :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is there any other way to show MS chart on an MVC view page rather than as an image? Because as an image I am unable to do the mouse over for the data points.